# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol, how to solve?

Tags: c++, lnk2001

I am sorry if this question has been asked before but I have looked at many answers and it hasn't helped me (or maybe I just don't know where to look exactly myself). I have been given this code to work with so its not my own code, hence why its harder for me to figure out. Plus I studied C# and not C++ even though there's probably not that big a difference. Here are the errors I'm getting:

> Branscan2K.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl fnDatabase32(void)" (__imp_?fnDatabase32@@YAHXZ)
>
> PicoloLiveImageView.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall EImage::EImage(void)" (__imp_??0?$EImage@UEBW8@@@@QAE@XZ)
>
> PicoloLiveImageView.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall EImage::~EImage(void)" (__imp_??1?$EImage@UEBW8@@@@UAE@XZ)
>
> PicoloLiveImageView.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl DoSave(char *)" (__imp_?DoSave@@YAXPAD@Z)

Answers I've seen so far range from missing library files to the definition of my functions not being in the program or project properties. Those haven't helped but it could be just the novice in me.

Comment: "there's probably not that big a difference" -- C++ and C# have pretty much nothing in common apart from some syntax that looks similar. In any case, you're missing the .lib file for a DLL whose header you included and used, which contains the missing functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I saw that one coming as I was writing it haha but thanks for clarifying! I finally fixed those errors but now have the following:


> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "easyms60.lib"


Any help is appreciated, I will start searching online as well. Cheers!

Comment: That's when the linker tries to open said file but cannot find it. Find out where easyms60.lib is and make sure its containing directory is listed as a library search path.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin! I sorted that now. I can now build the program without any errors, problem is when I try to run it gives me an error saying error accessing the registry. After that it asks if I want to backup the database but its not able to and it tells me to double check the location of the database. I'm trying to solve that problem now. Maybe its to vague for you without looking at the code. Thanks for all the help anyway.

Comment: Well that's functionality from your specific application, I can't help you further. Best of luck :)

Comment: No problem, thanks!